# How secure is it to upgrade bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind

The release notes of `bitcoin-core` suggest to just copy the `bitcoind` file, which appears on my system (Raspbian Butch) in `/usr/local/bin`.

Since I built from source using `./configure` I wonder how this will influence my node. Is `bitcoind` really the only thing that gets changed with a new release?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although certain releases perform database upgrades, the upgrade is handled by the bitcoind binary - updating a node only requires changing the binary, regardless of whether you downloaded a prebuilt one or compiled it from source.

If any additional changes to the bitcoin data are required, the updated bitcoind will perform them when it starts.

If you are downloading a prebuilt binary, make sure you get it from a reliable source (such as bitcoin.org) and verify the signatures to make sure it has not been tampered with.